# What assembly contains the ListBox class in WP8 Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, listbox, .net-assembly, windows-phone-8-emulator

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the ListBox class should be implemented in PresentationFramework.dll. However, I cannot find this DLL in the WP8 SDK emulator images.

What DLL contains the WP ListBox control?

UPDATE: After asking this question, I did some research and found the ListBox implementation in System.Windows.dll (System.Windows.ni.dll). But now the question turns into the following: why it does not correspond to the MSDN documentation and what online source should I use to know the real location of a class in Silverlight for WP?

Comment: I'd be interested to know what you're trying to do?

Comment: @WiredPrairie, I was going to decompile the ListBox class to see how the change notifications from the bound ObservableCollection are used. I need this to get the best performance when updating the collection.

Comment: You'll find very little of it is decompilable, as it's written in C++.

Comment: @WiredPrairie, but I didn't know that and should have given it a try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should still use MSDN, but I stumbled upon a few problems such as yours with it. The reason for this is because some classes come from a different dll wether you use it in Windows 8 developpment or windows phone 8 developpment

In this case, the msdn link for ListBox in WP8 is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

There is no real way to find your answer everytime (at least I didn't find one) but when the classic library doesnt work, I google the name of the library + windows phone 8 and it usually helps me finding the good one. Here it would be "ListBox windows phone 8", that's how I found the MSDN link

Hope it helps

Comment: It would be nice if we could find what we need from the main page for WP developers (http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us). Unfortunately, if I use the Search icon from there, I get [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listbox.aspx) for ListBox which even does not contain the assembly name. Can you tell us how you use search to find the "proper" pages?

Comment: I just google the name of the class I need + windows phone (example : Listbox windows phone) and usually the first link is the MSDN page for the class

Comment: I would post it as a possible answer but not a comment.